# Как адаптировать блок?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему, имею блок, который в свою очередь разделен еще на два, как мне сделать так, что бы при уменьшении размера экрана, блоки не съезжали, а основной блок уменьшался вместе с его содержимым, при этом сохраняя пропорции!?
Код:

```css
.myprof {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 53px 73px 53px;
}
.prof-left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.prof-right {
    width: 930px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myprof">
    <div class="prof-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450/&text=+LOGO" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="prof-right">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы хотите что бы при уменьшении экрана дочерние блоки остались друг возле друга? или второй под первым?

Comment: Друг возле друга.

Comment: Ну да я дал ответ в двух вариантах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот первый вариант, это не тот вариант что вы хотели, но может пригодиться.
И еще посмотрите второй.

```css
.myprof {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 53px 73px 53px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.prof-left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.prof-left>img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.prof-right {
    width: 930px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myprof">
    <div class="prof-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450/&text=+LOGO" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="prof-right">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

А в этом варианте блоки всегда будут друг возле друга. 
А размеры блоков можете поставить так как хотите в процентах.

```css
.myprof {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 53px 73px 53px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
.prof-left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
.prof-left>img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.prof-right {
    width: 930px;
    height: 450px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: calc(50% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="myprof">
    <div class="prof-left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450/&text=+LOGO" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="prof-right">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо огромное, то что нужно, один вопрос, а можно ли правый блок до конца растянуть, что-бы отступ справа, был такой же как и у картинки слева!?

Comment: @Toxa26 как видно сейчас здесь так показывает, но если у вас не так то манипулируете с `calc` и получите то что нужно

Comment: Оно так показывает только при таком разрешении экрана, а если развернуть на весь экран, то отступ справа увеличится...

Comment: @Toxa26 Ну да я сказал нужно манипулировать с `max-width: calc(50% - 5px);`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: Есть ещё вопрос, а возможно ли реализовать что-бы правый блок по высоте так же уменьшался?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получилось нормально при изменении размеров, в любом случае нельзя указывать строгие размеры в пикселях. Тут проценты, или flex. Можно, например, так, хотя это не очень хорошая разметка, но в качестве примера подойдет, думаю:

```css
.myprof {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 2%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.prof-left {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.prof-left img {
  width: 100%;
}

.prof-right {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myprof">
  <div class="prof-left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450/&text=+LOGO" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="prof-right">
    <p>Зима припорошила искрящимся снегом городские улицы, надела на деревья роскошный наряд. Мороз покрыл причудливыми узорами окна домов, заковал реку в ледяные оковы. На крышах домов выросли сосульки. Это значит, что скоро Новый Год! Новый Год – это самый
      волшебный, самый красивый, самый таинственный и веселый праздник!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: После определенной маленькой ширины блоки опять попадут друг под другом.